# Selling Android apps without being on the merchant list

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I would like to register a merchant account, but my country is not on the list. But I have a bank account in the US. Can I just use that when setting up merchant account or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are legal issues if you use just the Bank Account and are not a US citizen.

My solution was to register a company in USA, open a bank account under the company and sell through that. I've been using this for close to 2 years now, and have had no problems so far.

Comment: but i have dual citizenship, country i live in and US , does that make it ok ?

Comment: @MateKrižanac In that case it should be fine. You should still consult a lawyer though before you do this, but I think you'll be fine.